# Convert a date to ISO8601 date format

Tags: php, date-time

This is more of a PHP question than a WordPress one.

I have a custom post type event that by default outputs the date as  "September 11, 2011 9:00 am" format.

I'm trying to format the post in http://schema.org/Event format, I have converted every other part of the post to that format (place,address, etc) except the dates.

Any help on how to convert that format to ISO8601 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`the_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time) or [`get_the_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time), which accept the same format parameters as php's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
// assign to a variable
$iso8601_date = get_the_time('c');

// or output directly
the_time('c');
```

EDIT- converting formats with php:

```
$date = "September 11, 2011 9:00 am";
$time = strtotime( $date );
echo date( 'c', $time );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I forgot to mention that I'm using a plugin called event-calendar-pro and it outputs this time through a function called <?php echo sp_get_start_date(); ?> and I need to convert that to the ISO8601 format. Sorry for the confusion. I did not mean the date of the wordpress post.

Comment: @Sri - see edit above